# SQL: Update Field to NULL if Bound Value Equals it, Othewise Leave Untouched w/o PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a Table with a `NUMERIC(38,0)` field called `FOO`. In an `UPDATE` statement I'm already updating two other `VARCHAR2` fields, `BAR` and `BAZ`, unconditionally.

How can I cleverly update `FOO` to NULL if the bound value is equal to `FOO`, else leave it untouched? Due to various constraints, I need to be able to do this without PL/SQL.

Example #1: If the current record has `FOO` as 123, I need an `UPDATE` statement with `FOO=123, BAR='Abc', BAZ='Def'` to update `BAR` and `BAZ` and set `FOO` to `NULL`.

Example #2: If the current record has `FOO` as 123, I need an `UPDATE` statement with `FOO=299, BAR='Abc', BAZ='Def'` to update `BAR` and `BAZ`, but leave `FOO` as 123.

DB is Oracle

I've tried cooking up something clever with `BITAND` and `nvl` + others, but haven't quite found something that works.

Thanks! - vgort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
UPDATE MyTable A SET
A.FOO = CASE WHEN A.FOO = YourBoundFOO THEN NULL ELSE A.FOO END,
A.BAR = 'Abc',
A.BAT = 'Def'
WHERE...
```

EDIT - as per comment by Andriy M:

An alternative to the `CASE` would be to use

```
A.FOO = NULLIF (A.FOO,YourBoundFOO),
```

Comment: Yahia: While working on this, I also got the following to work:
`update MyTable
set FOO = DECODE(BITAND(FOO, <value>),<value>,NULL,FOO)
where ....`
<br>
Any idea which might be faster?

Comment: @user1037084 I would suspect my version since your version nests two function calls while mine is just doing a simple "IF THEN" - BUT I am really not sure, just measure it... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) any answer that was of help :-)

Comment: @Yahia: Your CASE expression is essentially the same as `NULLIF(A.FOO, YourBoundFOO)`, no?

Comment: @AndriyM yes, absolutely... added that to the post for future reference.